# Weird apache/PHP POST error

Tags: php, apache, security, post, filtering

After a few hours of searching for the error, I've found a reproducable test. It uses a simple form:

```
<form name="test" method="POST" action="test.php">
  <textarea name="content"></textarea>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

After filling the textarea with exactly `substring((SELECT` and hitting the button 'send' the server  returns a general error: `Connection with the server was reset while downloading`
I looked into http error_log but there are no reports for this.

Using:

```
Linux 2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.x86_64
Build Date  Jul 3 2012
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler 
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) 
Apache API Version  20051115 
PHP Version 5.3.3
```

test.php has no PHP code there is only the form. If I rename the file to test.html and change action="test.html" the error remains the same.

Tested on FF 15 and Chrome 21, (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Firebug: POST test.php Aborted 192.168.1.1 0 192.168.1.1:80

---

Is it possible that apache is filtering my POST data? I noticed that **substring((SELECT** is mentioned in several apache exploits. How can I disable this kind of filters?

I can not see any mod_security in my modules.

Comment: Exactly, show us `test.php` or we can't decide if this has anything to do with your code.

Comment: What browser are you using and is it the same result across all browsers?

Comment: what are your configs saying about timeouts?

Comment: Your Firebug request log please.

Comment: It looks like mod_security. Can you tell us a bit more about your hosting (shared/vps, hosting provider, etc)?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but from a bit of googling of those specific error codes/messages, this may not be coming from Apache at all.  I think you could be having router issues, filtering that is unrelated to the server.  Can you enter that same thing in a textarea on another site?

Comment: and let us see the request/responce headers please

Comment: try putting some content in test.php

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(apache_get_modules());
```

Does not list mod_security or an other security related module.